# Making a REST POST during the setup of a grinder script

Tags: rest, jython, grinder

Is there a way to post a piece of json data to a url when setting up a grinder test?  I have tried just using the http plugin however it throws the following error:

net.grinder.engine.common.EngineException: Must be called from worker thread

I have been trying to figure out how to do it with urllib2 however urllib2 seems to not have any way to post data such as json, just urls with parameters in them.  Other libraries that I normally use in python seem to be unavailable in jython.

Thanks!

Comment: What you want to do is certainly possible, although additional detail would probably help get the best answer.  One question that came to me right away: is it ok to do the POST once in the life cycle of each thread, one time only per agent process, or (in a case with a distributed test using many agents) one time only, period.  You can always reach for the Java HTTP libraries if the python ones are being wonky.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic way to do this. I have just gone through a run of searching all over google in order to do this. It works.

the header need to be set up using NVPair, and you need to tell whatever
it is receiving it that it is to expect a json object in the payload
that last hanging comma is required. You can add more headers, comma separated
NVPair objects, just remember to include the trailing comma.

```
payload = your json string (either load it from a file or create it programatically)
headers = ( NVPair("Content-type", "application/json"), ) 
requestString = "http://urlToPostTo"
request = HTTPRequest()
result = request.POST(requestString, payload, headers)
```

Here is the relevant API doc:
http://grinder.sourceforge.net/g3/script-javadoc/net/grinder/plugin/http/HTTPRequest.html